# What will be the efficient way to move 100 GB of data from a C# application to Cassandra or any similar big data storage?

Tags: c#, database, cassandra, bigdata

This 100 GB of data is from an electronics device and will be in the form of a file. 
Currently, our application produces 4 - 6 GB of data, which we are storing in Google Drive. 
What we are thinking is to set up servers and manually download the file from the tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might investigate a number of possibilities:

1 - Is it possible to compress the data, before trying to upload it, especially if the file format allow for high compression rates.

2 - Is it possible to apply to cleaning to the data file for redundant information, before compression and uploading. If the file contain significant repeated data fields, it might be possible to only keep data changes. And example could be a device reporting if a motor is running or not with 10 ms intervals. If the motor only turns on/off once every hour, then vast amount of information could be removed before uploading and without loosing information.

3 - Would it be possible to constantly stream the data, or maybe in smaller continuous chunks of say 10 or 100 Kb. Streaming data might make the end-to-end process flow more responsive, as wells as more resilient to network/internet dropouts.

4 - Maybe read a bit about how some IoT device patterns manage to upload the significant to the cloud in both online and offline situations.

If you provide more details about your setup, data file format etc. etc - it might be possible to provide more specific suggestions.